Win 10 slow boot time. I can't figure it out
My Server which hosts Plex, some virtual machines, etc has an extremely slow boot (5+ minutes) although once I'm in Windows it runs great. It is a Ryzen 3 with an NVMe and used to boot in less than 45 seconds. I've done the normal things like disabled anything unneeded in startup, update my BIOS, update my WD SN770 firmware, made sure I'm on a recent Windows update (Win 10 22H2) etc but nothing seems to help.
I could format the drive and reinstall Windows but I'm trying to avoid it if at all possible as this PC is my "server" and running some important things that I'd rather not have to setup again. Once I'm in Windows the computer runs fantastic with absolutely no lagging regardless of what I'm doing.
I've created an ETL file and tried to understand it but I'm at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance! [ETL file roughly 5.5gb] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/13t-9A9u-lpVbnXPze6-EjTd0sMJq-d2L/view?usp=sharing)

Run msconfig and enable boot logging. Boot, then go and interrogate the log file. the option is on the 'Boot' tab. The boot log is saved as a text file in the Windows directory. The file name is ntbtlog.txt

I got the log and browsed through but I didn't notice anything suspicious and unfortunately it doesn't give times on how long each driver took. log
